# How to make a custom pan control

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am student and working my own application for knowing how to use Google map API v3.
and i call a Java script function named "Up_pan"  from my application.

```
function Up_pan() {

    var center = map.getCenter();
    var New_center = { lat: center.lat() + 1,
        lng: center.lng() + 1
    };
    map.panto(New_center);
}
```

but it did not work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Classic question! Btw, there is no "Up_pan" function.

Comment: Please be more specific about what is not working. What fails? What is the specific problem? Do you get an error? Also, can you provide a link to your page, load your entire page, or set up a test on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? You haven't provided enough information for others to give you good feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
map.panto(New_center);
```

to

```
 map.panTo(New_center);
```

If that doesn't fix it, maybe you could try changing this:

```
var New_center = { lat: center.lat() + 1,
    lng: center.lng() + 1
};
```

to this:

```
var New_center = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 1, center.lng() + 1);
```

Comment: It didn't work too. Actually, i want to make a button in my application which act as "Pan up" control. Please help me.Thank for reading

Comment: I am really sorry but it also didn't work.Thank for helping me.I sure the function name is correctly.

Comment: I thank for help me alot^^. thank IsisCode. i missed first line for my child^^ without knowing.

Comment: This is my full code.
function up() {
         var center = map.getCenter();
        var New_center = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 1, center.lng() + 1);
        map.setCenter(New_center);
}
Thank everyone for  helping me.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution

```
new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 1, center.lng() + 1);
```

the panControl do not respect the Zoom, so if zoom it's too close, the left click send us to another continent rsrs

Something like this could be more appropriate

```
new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + (1 / map.getZoom()), center.lng() + (1 / map.getZoom()));
```